# NFC Read Tag with Android API

Tags: android, nfc

I am still learning the Android API.

Could someone give me some guidelines for using the Android API to enable NFC read tags?
What are the major items that have to happen in order to read the content of message?
What is the sequence of things that are supposed to happen? Does someone has a few lines of sample code?

For instance:

1. How to read the intent filter: do I use "PendingIntent"?
2. Does the app need to be able to handle exception? If yes, how.
3. How to use "NfcAdapter".

Comment: Please do a little google search before posting this kind of question. Prior knowledge of yours will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html) is what you need to get started. Read the basics section and you should be off :)

Comment: thank you Tobias, could you go to detail a bit. I m not sure after tag being discovered, how does code dispatch an app or release a text string? what are the API or action code suppose to take.

Comment: You really should read the document. It's all there. You need to update your manifest to have the correct permissions, to have an intent filter, etc. You can copy and paste from the document. You will then get an intent with an extra containing the info from the tag. I would highly recommend NDEF formatted tags. You can easily check the type and retrieve the payload from the extra.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://tapintonfc.blogspot.sg/2012/08/nfc-workshop-series-android-dispatch.html) NFC workshop series. this will help you.